# Jquery hover can't change background when hover ul li?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About &darr;</a>
       <ul id="nav-sub">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About &raquo;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>       
   </li>     
</ul>
```

And jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$("#nav li").hover(function(){ 
       $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400); 
        $('#nav-sub ul').css("background", "#380606");
        },function(){ 
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"}); 

        }); 
});
```

When I hover ul li, `$('#nav-sub ul').css("background", "#380606");` can't change background, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#nav-sub ul')` will select any ULs that are descendants of `#nav-sub`.  In your html, `#nav-sub` doesn't have any descendant Uls so nothing gets selected.

Perhaps you want to just do:

```
$('#nav-sub').css("background", "#380606");
```

or poossibly

```
 $('#nav-sub li').css("background", "#380606");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not `ul` it should be `li` as below

```
 $('#nav-sub li').css("background", "#380606");
```

Answer (score 0):

you just try to do something like this for each of the BG for `li`:

```
 $('ul#nav-sub li').css("background", "#380606");
```

or want to bg on `ul`:

```
$('ul#nav-sub').css("background", "#380606");
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/KtCeA/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple to do with CSS using the :hover selector

http://jsfiddle.net/2kguw/1/

```
ul#nav li{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
ul#nav li:hover{
    background: #380606;
}
```

or:
http://jsfiddle.net/2kguw/3/

```
ul#nav li{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
ul#nav li:hover{
    background: #380606;
}

ul#nav-sub{
    display:none;
}
li#about:hover ul#nav-sub{
    display:block!important;
}
```